# carrot2 and solr for local indexing

Tags: solr, workbench, carrot2

i have indexed a local folder with solr 6.5 with data_driven_schema_configs schema
i have install carrot2 web 3.15 and carrot workbench

it's ok : all work well

i want to open any one  file in the files list result ... 
when i use workbench (on linux ubuntu 14.04) i obtain a well formed url like"file:///mnt/xxx/yyy.pdf" but openlink does not work (nothing is open)

and when i use carrot2 web (on linux ubuntu 14.04), i obtain a bad formed url like "http://localhost:8080/mnt/xxx/yyy.pdf" (with firefox 52.0)

is there a solution to open a file in this context ?

regards
Fred

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to devise a way to serve these files yourself, such as exposing the directory through the `/mnt/xxx/yyy.pdf` endpoint on `localhost:8080`. Since these files refer to a *local path* where the indexing took place, these files won't be served automagically through a web interface.

If you're writing your own web frontend, you probably want to expose the content at a known location and then add the filename (or the complete path) after the host / path to allow users to download the content that way. This is however up to you - since the files aren't kept verbatim around in Solr (Solr doesn't host the files themselves, it indexes and stores the content), you'll have to solve this yourself. You can put the files in s3 and prefix the s3 host, in Google Cloud Storage, at a local webserver, etc.

Comment: thanks for your attention -- Yes, it's right ! but i work only on local for this test. In the two cases (carrot2 workbench and web frontend), url metadata contains "/mnt/xxx/yyy.pdf". The carrot2 workbench interpret it on "file:///mnt..." and web frontend interpret it on "http://localhost:8080/mnt..." (i have verified with firefox, safari, chrome, konqueror ...). When i put "file:///mnt/xxx/yyy.pdf" given by workbench into my web frontend (firefox in this case), it's ok, the pdf is well opened in another tab. The good way is it to transform the url metadata on solr indexing ? 
regards
Fred